# Difference between filiī and liberī

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, syntax, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, synonyms

I was reading Orberg's *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata* and I found the following sentences:

> Marcus et Quīntus sunt dūo filiī. [...] In familia Rõmāna tres līberī sunt.

Now I deduce both words mean "children", but where would I use one or another? (I looked up at some dictionaries but didn't explained the difference).

**Edit:** This question has led to some kind of debate whether liberī is only applied to children that are born-free. [See it](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/does-liberi-only-refer-to-free-children).

Comment: Welcome to the site! I added some tags to your question. Feel free to retag if you feel like it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Filius, i*** means "son"
***Liberi*** (masc. plur.) means "children" and more precisely children of free people, i.e. not slaves.

This family has 2 sons but 3 children. There probably is a daughter around somewhere.

Comment: Do you know how universal this rule is? Lewis and Short [cites a few examples](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfilius) of *filii* being used for children of both sexes, cf. Spanish *hijos*

Comment: Latin is an extremely flexible language that had (has) a long living history. Always possible to find examples and most dictionnairies will give those exceptional examples. However, the general rules is that of filius - liberi I outlined above. You also have "pueri". And as the roman society is very preoccupied with the households, personal status' and family, you'll find an impressive amount of words describing all that.

Comment: *Fīlius* singular can't be a daughter (that would be *fīlia*), but *fīliī* plural can sometimes include daughters as well: a group of males and females generally takes a masculine plural. But this is dependent on context, and the more common meaning is "sons".

Comment: Can you support the claim that liberi is "more precisely children of free people, i.e. not slaves"? Current view among etymologists is that liberi "children" and liber "free" are two unrelated words.

Comment: @fdb: De Vaan s.v. agrees with Thiebo's etymology.

Comment: @Cerberus. Yes, you are right. That is the majority view. But my objection was to the supposition that “liberi” must always have its etymological meaning. Plautus uses it for the offspring of sheep.

Comment: @fdb Oh, hah. That might actually be an interesting question. Can it ever be used for non-free humans? And is this usage Plauti for lambs metaphorical/ironic or normal?

Comment: More here: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/does-liberi-only-refer-to-free-children

Answer (score 4):

Incidentally, starting with Augustus, **having three children was honorable** and gave men "certain political advantages", whereas having less than three children "restricted a man's ability to accept inheritances and legacies" ([Edmondson 2015](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780195336467.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780195336467-e-026): 576).

See more on **ius trium liberorum** in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_trium_liberorum)  or in Edmondson 2015.